# SQL function-like WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've researched for a pretty long time and extensively already on this problem; so far nothing similar has come up. **tl;dr below**

Here's my problem below.

I'm trying to create a `SELECT` statement in SQLite with conditional filtering that works somewhat like a function. Sample pseudo-code below:

```
SELECT col_date, col_hour FROM table1 JOIN table2 
ON table1.col_date = table2_col_date AND table1.col_hour = table2.col_hour AND table1.col_name = table2.col_name
    WHERE
        IF table2.col_name = "a" THEN {filter these records further such that its table2.col_volume >= 600} AND
        IF table2.col_name = "b" THEN {filter these records further such that its table2.col_volume >= 550}
        BUT {if any of these two statements are not met completely, do not get any of the col_date, col_hour}
```

*I know SQLite does not support the `IF` statement but this is just to demonstrate my intention.

Here's what I've been doing so far. According to [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx) article, it is possible to transform `CASE` clauses into boolean logic, such that you will see here:

```
SELECT table1.col_date, table1.col_hour FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.col_date = table2.col_date AND table1.col_hour = table2.col_hour AND table1.col_name = table2.col_name
    WHERE
        ((NOT table2.col_name = "a") OR table2.col_volume >= 600) AND
        ((NOT table2.col_name = "b") OR table2.col_volume >= 550)
```

In this syntax, the problem is that I still get `col_date`s and `col_hour`s where at least one `col_name`'s `col_volume` for that specific `col_date` and `col_hour` did not meet its requirement. (e.g. I still get a record entry with `col_date = 2010-12-31` and `col_hour = 5`, but `col_name = "a"`'s `col_volume = 200` while `col_name = "b"`'s `col_volume = 900`. This said date and hour should not appear in the query because "a" has a volume which is not >= 600, even if "b" met its volume requirement which is >= 550.)

### For tl;dr

If all these are getting confusing, here are sample tables with the sample correct query results so you can just forget everything above and go right on ahead:

table1

```
col_date,col_hour,col_name,extra1,extra2
2010-12-31,4,"a","hi",1
2010-12-31,4,"a","he",1
2010-12-31,4,"a","ho",1
2010-12-31,5,"a","hi",1
2010-12-31,5,"a","he",1
2010-12-31,5,"a","ho",1
2010-12-31,6,"a","hi",1
2010-12-31,6,"a","he",1
2010-12-31,6,"a","ho",1
2010-12-31,4,"b","hi",1
2010-12-31,4,"b","he",1
2010-12-31,4,"b","ho",1
2010-12-31,5,"b","hi",1
2010-12-31,5,"b","he",1
2010-12-31,5,"b","ho",1
2010-12-31,6,"b","hi",1
2010-12-31,6,"b","he",1
2010-12-31,6,"b","ho",1
```

table2

```
col_date,col_hour,col_name,col_volume
2010-12-31,4,"a",750
2010-12-31,4,"b",750
2010-12-31,5,"a",200
2010-12-31,5,"b",900
2010-12-31,6,"a",700
2010-12-31,6,"b",800
```

The correct query results (with `col_volume` filters: 600 for 'a' and 550 for 'b') should be:

```
2010-12-31,4
2010-12-31,6
```

Comment: One issue from the logic you have explained is that it would appear that table2.col_name needs to be both "a" and "b" at the same time. "That said date and hour should not appear because "a" has a volume which is not >= 600, even though "b" met its volume requirement which is >= 550.)" I could understand if "a" came from table1 and "b" from table2.

Comment: Well, according to the article, "(Not A) or B" == "If A Then B". I literally just copied its logic hehe. The problem with this is that B is an assignment, not a further filter.

Comment: Think about this statement you made. "That said date and hour should not appear because "a" has a volume which is not >= 600, even though "b" met its volume requirement which is >= 550.)"

Comment: Edited my grammar a bit. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have an answer (BIG HELP to **@mucio**'s "HAVING" clause; looks like I have to brush up on that).

Apparently the approach was a simple sub-query in which the outer query will do a join on. It's a work-around (not really a direct answer to the problem I posted, I had to reorganize my program flow with this approach), but it got the job done.

Here's the sample code:

```
SELECT table1.col_date, table1.col_hour 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT col_date, col_hour 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE 
        (col_name = 'a' AND col_volume >= 600) OR 
        (col_name = 'b' AND col_volume >= 550) 
        GROUP BY col_date, col_hour 
        HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
    ) tb2 
ON 
table1.col_date = tb2.col_date AND 
table1.col_hour = tb2.col_hour 
GROUP BY table1.col_date, table1.col_hour
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
      SELECT table1.col_date, 
             table1.col_hour 
        FROM table1 
  INNER JOIN table2
          ON table1.col_date = table2.col_date 
         AND table1.col_hour = table2.col_hour 
         AND table1.col_name = table2.col_name
       WHERE EXISTS ( -- here I'm appling the filter logic 
                      select col_date,
                             col_hour
                        from table2 sub
                       where (col_name = 'a' and col_volume >= 600) 
                          or (col_name = 'b' and col_volume >= 550) 
                         and sub.col_date = table2.col_date 
                         and sub.col_hour = table2.col_hour 
                         and sub.col_name = table2.col_name
                    group by col_date,
                             col_hour
                      having count(1) = 2 -- I assume there could be only two rows:
                                          -- one for 'a' and one for 'b'
                    )
```

You can check this demo in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/62df3/8)

Last thing, you show the same columns from `Table1` that you use for the join, but I imagine this is just for the sake of this example

Comment: Hi! Sorry if my edit came too late, I tried running this on the latest table1 data. I do get the correct entries now, although they are duplicated thrice each (since table1 has multiple entries per date & hour & name). :O

Comment: then use distinct or group by :)

Comment: I'm taking a performance hit with this, but your "HAVING" clause has led me to the right approach! I'll post a complete answer soon!

Comment: yes, probably it's better to filter table2 values before doing the join

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `exists` and correlated subquery with `case` for different conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select t1.col_date
     , t1.col_hour
from table1 t1 
where exists ( select t2.col_volume
               from table2 t2
               where t2.col_date = t1.col_date
                 and t2.col_hour = t1.col_hour
                 and t2.col_name in ('a', 'b')
               group by t2.col_volume
               having count(t2.col_name >= case when t2.col_name = 'a' then 600 else 550 end) = (select count(*) from table2 where col_name = t2.col_name))
```

Comment: Used it on both sample and real data. It returns nothing though. :O

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean transformation is wrong.
Your IFs infer that you are looking for rows that:

- table2.col_name = "a" and col_volume >= 600
- table2.col_name = "b" and col_volume >= 550
- (implicitly) other values for col_name

So, to translate this to SQL:

```
SELECT     table1.col_date, table1.col_hour 
FROM       table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col_date = table2.col_date AND
           table1.col_hour = table2.col_hour
WHERE      (table2.col_name = 'a' AND table2.col_volume >= 600) OR
           (table2.col_name = 'b' AND table2.col_volume >= 550) OR
           (table2.col_name NOT IN ('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: Hi, sorry there are no other col_names. Just 'a' and 'b'. I tried running your code; I still encounter the problem I mentioned in my post.